# character pointers

Tags: c++

is it like `char *pch='a';` means pch holds value `97` and is a pointer to another char whereas `char *pch="avinash";` means that `pch` holds the pointer pointing to a of avinash.

Comment: possible duplicate of [character pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231923/character-pointers)

Answer (score 1):

`char *pch='a';` shouldn't compile on any standard-compliant compiler.

`char* pch = "absljsdf"` is deprecated. you must use `const`.

`const char * pcch = "abdsfkjsdf";` means that pcch points to the first character in "abdsfkjdf", but you can't modify the contents of the string with that pointer. hth

Answer (score 1):

char *pch="avinash"; is a string literal and what you said is right.
but the first one is a compile error.
did you try compiling them and seeing the values?

Answer (score -1):

No.

```
char * pch='a';
```

means that the address of pch is the value of 'a' which most likely points to an invalid part of the memory :-). If you want to set pch to point to 'a' you need to first allocate memory and then set

```
*pch = 'a';
```

for instance.

Comment: One would need a reinterpret_cast.

Comment: @fnokke..is it not that 'a' is decoded to its ascii code value and the statement becomes equivalent to char *pch= 197...now pch will point to the char in address location 197

Comment: @avinash well it depends on how you see it. I focused on the importance to know the difference that pointer values are addresses. In this case the compiler helps since it finds a type mismatch (by setting type of 'a' to char and not char *). If you would have set char * pch = 0x61 (the value of 'a') you might not have a gotten a compiler error (and instead a segmentation fault when trying to access the memory that pch points to).

Comment: But as of Armens answer I realized that this confusion had less to do with pointers and more to do with the 'a' and "a" notation (where the second alternative is implicitly typed as const char * as noted above). Anyway I am sorry that this was not helpful.